# Kubernetes Metrics Server no metrics known for some Pods

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, metrics-server

I have the following deployments one of Django api and the other of celery, when I run the command to get the resource consumption of the pods, it only return those of celery and not those of the API. What are potential reasons for this? given that the same configuration works well on another cluster

Kubernetes Server Version: v1.22.5

[image]

**EDIT: Added logs of metrics server**

```
I0824 13:28:05.498602       1 serving.go:342] Generated self-signed cert (apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt, apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key)
I0824 13:28:06.269888       1 requestheader_controller.go:169] Starting RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I0824 13:28:06.269917       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I0824 13:28:06.269966       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:201] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file"
I0824 13:28:06.269981       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I0824 13:28:06.270005       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:201] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
I0824 13:28:06.270025       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I0824 13:28:06.270512       1 secure_serving.go:266] Serving securely on [::]:8443
I0824 13:28:06.270577       1 dynamic_serving_content.go:131] "Starting controller" name="serving-cert::apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt::apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key"
I0824 13:28:06.270593       1 tlsconfig.go:240] "Starting DynamicServingCertificateController"
W0824 13:28:06.270852       1 shared_informer.go:372] The sharedIndexInformer has started, run more than once is not allowed
I0824 13:28:06.277601       1 server.go:187] "Failed probe" probe="metric-storage-ready" err="no metrics to serve"
I0824 13:28:06.371038       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file 
I0824 13:28:06.371093       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController 
I0824 13:28:06.371932       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
```

Comment: Can you please check the `metrics-server` logs and search for entries of the `api-xxxx` pods? Both workloads are running with the same nodeSelectors/tolerations, or there is a chance that they are scheduled on nodes with different container runtime versions?

Comment: Thank you for answering Eduardo, I added the logs. The pods are running in the same node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my cluster to 1.23.4 and my HPAs to autoscaling/v2 api and now everything works fine, I suppose my problem was related to this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/76292) because my api pod had an initContainer.